# Is there an R function for merging or replace the elements of a vector from a translation table?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have two data frames. First one is a "translation table" (`df1`) in which I have the name of a species in one column, and the coded name in another one.
The second data frame is a table in which I have a column with the species names. I would like to create a new column with the coded names corresponding to the species of the same row.

df1:

```
name    code
Ammi-majus  Amaj
Anacamptis-pyramidalis  Apyr
Daucus-carota   Dcar
Arctium-lappa   Alap
```

df2:

```
sp.name
Ammi-majus
Anacamptis-pyramidalis
Daucus-carota
Daucus-carota
Daucus-carota
Daucus-carota
Arctium lappa
Arctium lappa
Arctium lappa
```

This is what the new column should look like:

```
sp.namecode
Ammi-majus  Amaj
Anacamptis-pyramidalis  Apyr
Daucus-carota   Dcar
Daucus-carota   Dcar
Daucus-carota   Dcar
Daucus-carota   Dcar
Arctium lappa   Alap
Arctium lappa   Alap
Arctium lappa   Alap
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you show your dataframes in a matrix format, so that it comes clear what your example data frame looks like?

Comment: I think you're looking for `merge`.

Comment: full_join from dplyr is also possible. But it is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: `merge(sp, codes, by.x="sp.name", by.y="name")` and `sp %>% left_join(codes, by=c("sp.name"="name"))` I think solve your issue. where sp is `df1` and `codes` is `df2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future readers the result the author wants can be achieved both by using baser and dplyr functions:

#### `baser`:

```r
merge(sp, codes, by.x="sp.name", by.y="name")
```

#### `dplyr`:

```r
sp %>% left_join(codes, by=c("sp.name"="name"))
```

#### data:

```r
sp <- read.table(header=T, text="sp.name
Ammi-majus
Anacamptis-pyramidalis
Daucus-carota
Daucus-carota
Daucus-carota
Daucus-carota
Arctium-lappa
Arctium-lappa
Arctium-lappa")

codes <- read.table(header=T, text="name    code
Ammi-majus  Amaj
Anacamptis-pyramidalis  Apyr
Daucus-carota   Dcar
Arctium-lappa   Alap")
```